# Shortest Port Scanner

Tags: code-golf

Write the shortest program that will attempt to connect to open ports on a remote computer and check if they are open. (It's called a [Port Scanner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner))

Take input from command line arguments.

```
your-port-scanner host_ip startPort endPort
```

Assume, startPort < endPort (and `endPort - startPort < 1000`)

**Output:** All the open ports between that range should space or comma seperated.

Comment: Are there any legal reasons to go about using port scanners?  Except to stop other people hacking into your network by closing unnecessary ports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### sh/netcat, 39

```
nc -vz $1 $2-$3 2>&1|cut -f3 -d\ |xargs
```

Netcat does the scanning and returns results in this form on standard error:

```
localhost [127.0.0.1] 22 (ssh) open
localhost [127.0.0.1] 25 (smtp) open
```

`cut` and `xargs` extract the port number and make a single line out of it.

Remind me to shut SMTP down on that node.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 92

```
$_='use I;$h=shift;grep I->new("$h:$_"),shift..shift';
s/I/IO::Socket::INET/g;@_=eval;say"@_"
```

Perl 5.10 or later, run with `perl -E 'code here'`.

Uses regexes to compress that long `IO::Socket::INET`, then `eval`; final formatting done with array interpolation.

By request, a more detailed explanation. To ungolf, let's first respace:

```
$_ = << 'EOC';
  use I;
  $h = shift;
  grep I->new("$h:$_"), shift..shift;
EOC
s/I/IO::Socket::INET/g;
@_ = eval;
say "@_";
```

The line before the `eval` replaces all (two) occurences of 'I' with 'IO::Socket::INET', that's a standard Perl golfing trick to reduce the impact of unavoidable long identifiers.  Naming a few of the temporaries, the code is then equivalent to this:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
$h = shift;
$p1 = shift;
$p2 = shift;
@_ = grep IO::Socket::INET->new("$h:$_"), ($p1 .. $p2);
say "@_";
```

In a nutshell: read host and port range arguments from the command line; attempt a connection to all of them in sequence (`IO::Socket::INET->new()`); keep a list of those who succeeded (`grep`); display the result nicely (`say`).

Comment: cant understand somehow :( looks like deepest black magic for me :P but still a +1 for weirdness

Comment: @masterX244 I've detailed the innards a bit. HTH

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby - 85

```
require"socket"
h,p,e=$*
p.upto(e){|p|begin
TCPSocket.new h,p
$><<"#{p} "
rescue
end}
```

Answer (score 1):

## sh/nmap/GNU grep/xargs - 36

```
nmap -p$2-$3 $1|grep -Po '^\d+'|xargs
```

Follows input and output specs:

```
$ sh 1109.sh 127.0.0.1 1 80
22 25 80
```

Comment: I don't know if `nmap` counts as a valid answer here, but it is **definitely not** `sh` :)

Comment: The output format could also use a little polishing.

Comment: @Eelvex that's a sh script, with a `your-port-scanner host_ip startPort endPort` interface, calling nmap ;-)

Comment: @J B, done :-) __

Comment: does `nmap` come bundled with linux? :-\ i didn't know that... :(

Comment: Is that a requirement ? I didn't seen this in the question ;-) php, ruby, golfscript, C compilers, ... are not installed by default on linux boxes neither ;-)

Comment: @user300, C compilers do, don't they?

Comment: No, no C compiler by default. You don't need a C compiler on most linux box. If you are thinking of "compiling programs", we use package managers these days. And I can't figure why `nmap` wouldn't be a valid answer while `nc` is ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 178

I'm new to Perl, any advice on shortening is appreciated!

```
use IO::Socket::INET;for($x=$ARGV[1];$x<$ARGV[2]+1;$x++){if(fork()){if($sock=new IO::Socket::INET(PeerAddr=>$ARGV[0],PeerPort=>$x,Proto=>'tcp')){print"$x ";}close($sock);exit;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## BASH - 105

In pure BASH (i.e no nmap or netcat).

```
exec 2>&- && exec 2<> /dev/null
for p in $(seq $2 $3); do
    > /dev/tcp/$1/$p &&
    echo -n "$p "
done
```

When using with an address other than localhost the timeout is quite long (in the order of minutes) when encountering a closed port so some sort of timeout/alarm function would be required in all likelihood.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - 70

```
<?for(list(,$h,$p,$e)=$argv;$p<=$e;++$p)@fsockopen($h,$p)&&print"$p ";
```

Comment: i'm sure you can squeeze the `$p++` in other mention of `$p`, will save one char...